# Python programming - Output issue in "Create a class function"

Tags: python

I'm from NON computer science background (Biochemist). In Python programming under "Create a class function", I didn't get the output for the following written function:

```
 class circle (object):
      def __init__(self, 10, 'red'):
          self.radius=10;
          self.color='red'
```

I got syntax error like this:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-ab699251caa9>", line 2
def_init_(self,10,'red'):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: function parameters should be names, like `self`, `param1`, `x` or `not_a_number`. Not `10` or `'red'`. Replace these with appropriately named arguments, or omit these arguments completely and simply use `10` and `'red'` in the function itself

Answer (score 0):

you cant pass pure value you need to pass it with variables

```
class circle (object):
      def __init__(self,number=10,color='red'):
          self.radius=number
          self.color=color
```

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters must be variables, not numbers or strings. Change this:

```
 class circle (object):
  def __init__(self, 10, 'red'):
      self.radius = 10
      self.color = 'red'
```

to this:

```
 class circle (object):
  def __init__(self, radius, color):
      self.radius = radius
      self.color = color
```

This class can be instantiated with:

```
myCircleObject = circle(10, 'red')
```

or, if you want to make the association parameter-value more clear, you can instantiate with:

```
myCircleObject = circle(radius = 10, color = 'red')
```

You can also set default values for the parameters:

```
class circle (object):
  def __init__(self, radius = 10, color = 'red'):
      self.radius = radius
      self.color = color
```

In this way, you can still instantiate the object as before but you can also init with:

```
myCircleObject = circle()
```

In this case, radius and color will have the default values specified in the signature (radius will be 10 and the color will be 'red').

Note that to avoid misinterpretations, parameters with default values can only be listed in the rightmost part. So if you want to specify a default value only for the parameter radius, you need to move it to the right:

```
class circle (object):
  def __init__(self, color, radius = 10):
      self.radius = radius
      self.color = color
```